# QQmlApplicationEngine not completely unloading qml components

Tags: qt, qml, qqmlengine

I'm currently loading my main.qml using QQmlApplicationEngine and works fine, and then I want to switch to main2.qml (without calling quit() on my QQmlApplicationEngine since that triggers QCoreApplication::exit() which will exit my application). 
So I just delete my engine, make a new one and set the context properties again (not the same context properties for main.qml slightly different), and it loads fine. Then I switch back to main.qml (load main.qml again) and I start getting warnings like

```
qrc:/qml/...: Cannot read property of null
```

That particular property is null in the context of main.qml so this is correct, but it is not null in the context of main2.qml. But my question is why don't I get the warning when I load main.qml the first time? I only seem to get the warning if I load main.qml after I have loaded main2.qml.

Your help is appreciated.

EDIT: Here is a simple example code

```
QSharedPointer<QQmlApplicationEngine> m_engine;
QQmlContext* m_ctxt;

void loadEngine(int window){
    m_engine->clearComponentCache();
    m_engine.reset(new QQmlApplicationEngine, &QObject::deleteLater);
    m_ctxt = m_engine->rootContext();

    m_ctxt->setParent(m_engine.get());
    QVector<QQmlContext::PropertyPair> qmlProperties;

    qmlProperties.push_back(QQmlContext::PropertyPair{"object", QVariant::fromValue(object)});

    if(window == 1){
        qmlProperties.push_back(QQmlContext::PropertyPair{"object1", QVariant::fromValue(object1)});
        // add more context properties

        m_ctxt->setContextProperties(qmlProperties);
        m_engine->load(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/qml/main.qml")));
    }
    else{    
        qmlProperties.push_back(QQmlContext::PropertyPair{"object2", QVariant::fromValue(object2)});
        // add more context properties

        m_ctxt->setContextProperties(qmlProperties);
        m_engine->load(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/qml/main2.qml")));
    }
}
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: Apart from the fact that reloading QML root file is a strange idea and recreating QML engine (that's an even stranger idea) why not reuse `QQmlApplicationEngine::load()` with the new file?

Comment: @folibis what do you mean reuse QQmlApplicationEngine::load()? Just call m_engine->load() with out recreating QML engine?

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to recommend you use a QML Loader component to change current viewable view. On this page you can find a few examples how to use Loader(s) https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html.

In this case you have to provide both context properties for "object1" and "object2".